# Google map API v3 event click raise when clickingMarkerClusterer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, markerclusterer

I have a [Google Map API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) [map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) object on a page that uses [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/). I have a function that need to run when we click on the map to it is registered as:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    CallMe(event.latLng);
});
```

So my problem is as follows: When I click on a cluster of `MarkerClusterer` instead of behaving like a marker and not raise the click event on the map but only the one from the marker it calls the click from the map.

To test this I have generated an alert from the `markerclusterer` click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, "clusterclick", function (cluster) {
    alert('MarkerClusterer click event');
});
```

So the `clusterclick` rises after the click event of map object. I then can't remove the listener of map object as a solution. Is there any way to test if there was a clusterer click in the click event of the map? Or a way to replicate the marker behaviour and do not raise the click event of map when `clustererclick` is called? Google and documentation didn’t help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is something that works but I'm still open to other better answers.

I use a setTimeout to relay the map click event to be the last thing javascript should execute and check with a boolean if clustererclick was raised before with something like this :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!clusterClicked) {
            CallMe(event.latLng);
            alert('Map click executed');
        }
        else {
            clusterClicked = false;
            alert('ClusterClicked map click not executed');
        }
    }, 0);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, "clusterclick", function (cluster) {
    clusterClicked = true;
});
```

Comment: Does that work? What happens, when I first click on a cluster setting `clusterclick` to `true` and then click elsewhere on the map?

Answer (score 4):

I had same problems and the solution i ended up with:

```
ClusterIcon.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    this.div_ = document.createElement('DIV');
    if (this.visible_) {
        var pos = this.getPosFromLatLng_(this.center_);
        this.div_.style.cssText = this.createCss(pos);
        this.div_.innerHTML = this.sums_.text;
    }

    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.div_);

    var that = this;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function(e) {
        =======> e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //<====================
        that.triggerClusterClick();
    });
};
```

I hate doing this but in other hand it's normal to "extend" external libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that may work.  Find the following code inside markerclusterer.js:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function() {
  that.triggerClusterClick();
});
```

and change it to:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function(ev) {
  ev.cancelBubble = true;
  if (ev.stopPropagation) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
  }
  that.triggerClusterClick();
});
```

According to Martin Matysiak of Google "this is called event propagation, the event always "bubbles" up in the DOM hierarchy. You can stop this from happening with [that] code."

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/PGeNrzv_SAs

Comment: Making changes to the google library may cause unknown issues. Hence not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method, inspired by the other answers, but without copy-pasting library code or changing the library itself:

```
originalOnAdd = ClusterIcon.prototype.onAdd;
ClusterIcon.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    originalOnAdd.call(this);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function (ev) {
        ev.cancelBubble = true;
        if (ev.stopPropagation)
            ev.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```